# Не работает else If JavaScript

Tags: javascript, if

Не работает JavaScript код
Начал проходить операторы if else но код не работает помогите пожалуйста

```
<!Doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <style>
            </style>
            <script>
                function t(){
                    var n, p;
                    n = document.getElementById('x1').value;
                    p = document.getElementById('out');
                    n = parseInt(n);
                    if(n<10){
                        p.innerHTML = "Привет малыш";
                    }
                    else if(n<25){
                        p.innerHTML = "Вы вполне молодой человек";
                    }
                    else if(n<50){
                        p.innerHTML = "Вы зрелый";
                    }
                    else{
                        p.innerHTML = "Вы пожилой"
                    }

            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            Введите ваш возраст:<input type="text" id='x1'>
            <button onclick="t()">Вывод</button>
            <hr>
            <p id="out"></p>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

У вас функция не закрыта:

```html
<!Doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <style>
            </style>
            <script>
                function t(){
                    var n, p;
                    n = document.getElementById('x1').value;
                    p = document.getElementById('out');
                    n = parseInt(n);
                    if(n<10){
                        p.innerHTML = "Привет малыш";
                    }
                    else if(n<25){
                        p.innerHTML = "Вы вполне молодой человек";
                    }
                    else if(n<50){
                        p.innerHTML = "Вы зрелый";
                    }
                    else{
                        p.innerHTML = "Вы пожилой"
                    }
               }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            Введите ваш возраст:<input type="text" id='x1'>
            <button onclick="t()">Вывод</button>
            <hr>
            <p id="out"></p>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Для подобных ошибок есть соответствующая причина для закрытия: Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой. Хотя похожие вопросы могут быть уместны на этом сайте, решение для этого вопроса вряд ли поможет будущим посетителям.....их надо закрывать, а не отвечать (разве что имеет смысл в комментарии подсказать где ошибка и показать как их находить)